# Python Sphinx imported method organization within a class

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a Class that is importing many methods from submodules. Currently Sphinx is setup to organize 'bysource' so they're at least sorting by the order in which the submodules are imported.

What I would like though, is some kind of header or searchable text for the title of the file they come from.

**Current Directory Structure:**

```
my_project
├── setup.py
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py # Classes for subpackage_1 and subpackage_2 and imports occur here
    ├── subpackage_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── _submodule_a.py
    │   └── _submodule_b.py
    └── subpackage_2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── _submodule_c.py
        └── _submodule_d.py
```

**Sphinx module rst file:**

```
Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: my_package
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :member-order: bysource
```

In the my_package init.py there are there parent Classes defined where all the submodules/methods are imported to their related Class.

```
class MyClass_1():
    ...
    from .subpackage_1._submodule_a import method_a
    from .subpackage_1._submodule_b import method_b, method_c

class MyClass_2():
    ...
    from .subpackage_2._submodule_c import method_d, method_e
    from .subpackage_2._submodule_d import method_f
```

In the resulting Sphinx method documentation I see the methods under each class, but the desire is to be able to see which submodule file the methods sourced from. Doesn't have to be a subsection, merely including a header/note etc. would be nice without having to resort to manually listing all the modlues/methods in the Sphinx file.

There's hundreds of functions in the real package so it would be helpful for the user to be able to quickly discern what submodule file a method came from when viewing the documentation.

| **Current Sphinx Output:** | **Desired Sphinx Output:** |
| --- | --- |
| Class MyClass_1... | Class MyClass_1... |
|  | *submodule_a* |
| * method_a | * method_a |
|  | *submodule_b* |
| * method_b | * method_b |
| * method_c | * method_c |
| Class MyClass_2... | Class MyClass_2... |
|  | *submodule_c* |
| * method_d | * method_d |
| * method_d | * method_e |
|  | *submodule_d* |
| * method_f | * method_f |

I see worse case scenario, putting the submodule filename in docstring for each method within the file, but would love if someone's figured this out in a more automated fashion

Comment: There are several ways to get your desired output. But if you think about it importing functions inside of classes isn't the best way to organize your objects. This is very similar to costum imports in the `__init__.py` file where you only want to expose part of your API. But the point is, what you're documenting for users is the publicly exposed part, not the part that's private and masked behind costume imports.

Comment: There's also the issue that if someone tries to answer, you likely won't like the result after you actually see it. Are you sure you want to group modules inside of classes as headings of functions (shouldn't methods be inside of functions)?

Comment: Thanks @bad_coder, and I agree on most of the thoughts. The submodules are organized the way they are to align with the way the vendor groups their API functions (this is a python wrapper for a product API). I also didn't want a user to have to import each submodule to get the underlying functions and rather just import the class that instantiates. Do you have a suggestions/links to another way of handling the submodules?